# render_to_string stripping markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `render_to_string` within a JSON 'render' response. The `render_to_string` method seems to be striping my HTML, what am I doing wrong here?

Here's a sample:

```
render :json => {:html => render_to_string(:partial => 'view', :locals => { data => @data} )}
```

The response is coming through without any markup on it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the template format in the respond_to block like this:

```
format.json do
  @template.template_format = :html
  @html = render_to_string( :partial => 'view', :locals => { data => @data}  )
  render :json => { :success => true, :html => @html }
end
```

Comment: The problem is I'm using this with the Ajax Upload plugin so I don't even have a true response block. This all a bit of hack to be honest. I could just return the data and have the client build the needed HTML but it would be nice to use the partial template.